# libmpi.so.12 cannot open shared object file when I have libmpi.so.40 and libmpi.so

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, mpi

So I am trying to compile an MPI program and it says libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file. But I don't understand why it's even asking for that file since I have libmpi.so.40.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: What program?  It appears you may have a version mismatch, but you need to provide a lot more details.  What OS? What compiler?  What version?  What software are you compiling?  What arguments are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: Consider sharing more information -  what are the command(s) and the exact error message for each command.

Comment: you might be trying to link your app with a library built with an older version (and possibly a different vendor) of MPI. Anyway, your question is very incomplete as is.